# I need to read a file and search for 1st occurrence of specific string so that i can copy it to another file

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

update Sample data file is below:

```
empid;1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
dept;112
JOD;20170101
empid;A2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
age;92
empid;1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
dept;Geology
JOD;20180607
empid;1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200d
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

I need to search for all attributes and copy the first occurrence of each to a nother file.
output should look like :

```
empid;1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
JOD;20170101
empid;2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
empid;1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
JOD;20180607
empid;1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

2nd occurrence of `dept` should not be considered if in each set of values

```
empid,empname,salary,dept,age,JOD.
```

CURRENLTY i am using below code:

```
awk -v FS=';' OFS=';'{ 
if ($1 == "empid" || $1 == "empname" || $1 == "salary" || $1 == "dept" || $1 == "age" || $1 == "JOD" ) print $0 }' FILE_NAME > NEW_FILE_NAME.
```

but its taking second occurrence of `dept` also.
Please guide me through it.

Comment: It looks as if the example data is basically four concatenated records, is that correct? Each record starts with the `empid` attribute, and ends with the `JOD` attribute?

Comment: Hi @kusalananda, this is column based data, that means attributes are coming in 1st field and 2nd fields are having respective values.. they are not conctenated. May be its was a issue while question was posted.

Comment: Sure, I can see there are two columns. But the data seems to be made up of four _sets of rows_, each set of rows constituting the entry for an employee (a "record" for that person).

Comment: yes that's correct @Kusalananda, i Thought you all are seeing the sample data in a text /line/row format. But they are actually 6 set of values as i have mentioned: EMPID EMPNAME SALARY DEPT AGE JOD. there can be a possibility that data for some attribute is missing from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that Kusalananda is right, and that each employee record starts with the line `empid`, the following `awk` command should work:

```
awk -F';' '$1=="empid" {delete a} !a[$1]++' input.txt > output.txt
```

This uses an array variable `a` to track which of the attribute names was already encountered, and print the current line only if that was not yet the case. The array is reset every time the `empid` attribute is encountered.

For a more in-depth explanation:

- `$1=="empid" {delete a}` will delete the array `a` every time a new record starts
- `!a[$1]++` makes use of the `awk` shorthand notation that a `1` outside of a conditional rule means "print the line", whereas a `0` would mean "don't print".
- The `a[$1]++` will increase an "occurence counter" for every value of the attribute name, which here is taken as "array index".
- The evaluation `!a[$1]++` will *first* check if the current value of the array entry is zero (i.e. the attribute was not yet encountered), perform the `print` action if true (thanks to the negation operator), and increase the counter *afterwards* (this works the same as prefix/postfix increment in C-style programming languages). Thus, if the attribute was not yet encountered, it is printed, but later occurences are ignored.

**Note** that while the `delete a` statement conforms to a syntax that was accepted to POSIX standard in 2012, and the above works on GNU `awk`, `mawk` and `nawk`, Stéphane Chazelas pointed out that for those implementations that don't support this syntax, the

```c
delete a
```

should be replaced by

```c
split("",a)
```

Comment: Clever and shorter than what I was working on. Setting `OFS` is not needed though, so `-F ';'` would be enough.

Comment: To increase portability, you can replace `delete a` with `split("", a)`.

Comment: thanks you @AdminBee, but the data is in Column format, means 1st column is having attnames and 2nd field/columns is having there respective values.  it may have been shown in a different way while question was uploaded. Please look at the question once again .

Comment: @Naresh I am usure if I correctly understand your comment.How does the output of my suggested `awk` command differ from the desired output as stated in your question? I tested it with your sample input copy-and-pasted into a file, and the output looked just like you stated under "output should look like".

Comment: @Adminbee thank you so much for your time, that comment was for , if you are able to see that sample data in row format. Anyways i will try to test your solution and will update accordingly. Thanks you so much

Comment: Hi @AdminBee, i have tried out your solution and it worked perfectly, but i am facing another type of scenario.. i have updated sample data file and desired output file. I would be grateful if you could guide me through it as well. -Naresh

Comment: @Naresh ok, this is of course a game changer. In order to keep this question thread as useful and understandable as possible for a wide range of people who may be facing a similar problem, I would ask you to undo your last edit and then either consider _this_ question solved and ask a new question with the "additional" constraint, or edit your current question by adding an "Addendum" or "P.S." (or however you like to call it) which then describes the new challenge separately. In the meantime: are the "surplus" `empid` lines guaranteed to _directly_ follow the first one of every record?

Comment: @Naresh Rather than asking follow-up question in comments, consider asking a new question.

Comment: Apologies gentlemen, I will post a new question on this new scenario. As i am a new user to Unix stack exchange , @AdminBee I am not sure how to add ADDENDUM or P.S.

Comment: @Naresh no need to become formal ;) When you post your new question, you can link to this one (see the formatting help on how to include hyperlinks) using the [URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585326/377345) in the "share" link below this question. And I see you already reverted the edit to this question ;)

Comment: sure i will @AdminBee . thanks you so much for you precious time. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is the same basic idea as [AdminBee's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585328/22222), but slightly less elegant (I store all values in memory for no good reason), albeit slightly shorter:

```
gawk -F';' '$1=="empid"{i=$2} ++a[i][$1]==1' file
```

We set `i` to the employee ID if the first field is `empid`. Then, we take advantage of a nice little trick in awk: when an expression evaluates to true, awk will print the line. So, `a[i][$1]` is an element of a two dimensional array, whose first key is the current `empid` (stored as `i`) and whose second key is the 1st field of the current line (`a[i][$1]`). Since `++` adds one to this, the expression `++a[i][$1]==1` will be true only for the first time each field is seen for a particular `empid`. Since we only print if it is true, the command will print the first occurrence for each id.

Note that this requires GNU awk.