# Read a file and search for 1st occurrence of specific string and matches certain patterns only

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

This question is a continuation of a question [I have asked earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585336/404445)

Sample data file:

```
empid;A1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
dept;112
JOD;20170101 
empid;#201
empid;A2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
age;92
empid; #3300
empid;A1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
dept;Geology
JOD;20180607
empid; #XY123
empid;A1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200d
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

I need to ignore the empid's with `#` or say just match those empid which have `A` as the first character and Match only the first occurence of each attributes from a set of attributes: `empid`,`empname`,`salary`,`dept`,`age`,`JOD`.

So that output should look like below output file:

```
empid;A1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
JOD;20170101
empid;A2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
empid;A1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
JOD;20180607
empid;A1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

Please guide me through it and let me know if anything else is required from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every employee record starts with an `empid` line, we can simply modify the answer to the previous question by ignoring altogether (i.e. don't print, and don't take as "start-of-record" tag) the "malformed" `empid` lines:

```
awk -F';' '$1=="empid"{if ($2!~/^A/) next; delete a}  !a[$1]++' input.txt > output.txt
```

This will ignore all lines where the "value" field of `empid` lines does *not* start with `A` by issuing a `next` command if such a line was found.

Apart from that, we again use an array to store how often a given attribute name was already encountered in the current record, and skip any attributes which were already seen in this record. Encountering an `empid` line will reset the array for the new record (as long as it contains a "valid" ID as per your definition).

Again, on `awk` versions that don't implement the `delete a` statement for an *entire* array variable, this command needs to be replaced with

```
split("",a)
```

to reset the array.

Comment: thanks @AdminBee, i will test out your suggestion and will let you know.. :)